# Cumulus CI:Logging into an Org(Sanbbox) is error out

Tags: connected-apps, cumulusci

I am using Cumulus CI to try robotframework for salesforce automation. Following https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html as a reference to configure the sandbox.

Everything went well till I reach a step where I need to logging into an Org(Sanbdbox) after configuring Connected App as a service. (I have created Connected App manually and used consumer key and secret key to configure this as a service)

When I run either of below commands I get below error and the org OAuth2 doesn't get configured in keychain.

"cci org connect <org_name> " OR
"cci org connect <org_name> -- sandbox" OR
"cci org connect REGSIT --login-url https://test.salesforce.com"

Error: Error: an integer is required (got type NoneType)

Any clue what am I doing wrong or if I am missing something ?

Please find below log:

```
cci error gist

CumulusCI version: 3.15.0
Python version: 3.8.5 (c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\scripts\python.exe)
Environment Info: Windows / AMD64


Last Command Run
================================
C:\Users\Swati\.local\bin\cci org connect REGSIT --login-url https://test.salesforce.com
Launching web browser for URL https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG90J3nJBMnqrStN2Bcb.sCyJJgU9NLmfg7wWYuDoyKPf2lXUPhC8LPUo8XNj4IzGOgSEoWJRFtwEctksyQ&redirect_uri=https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/callback&scope=web%20full%20refresh_token&prompt=login
Error: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
Run this command for more information about debugging errors: cci error --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 225, in main
    cli(standalone_mode=False)
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 168, in new_func
    func(RUNTIME, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 910, in org_connect
    oauth_dict = oauth_capture()
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\oauth\salesforce.py", line 158, in __call__
    self._create_httpd()
  File "c:\users\swati\.local\pipx\venvs\cumulusci\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\oauth\salesforce.py", line 179, in _create_httpd
    self.httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, OAuthCallbackHandler)
  File "c:\users\swati\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "c:\users\swati\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "c:\users\swati\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

Comment: CumulusCI comes with a Connected App built-in - you don't need to create one unless you have a specific reason to do so. Could you run `cci error gist` and [edit] the complete traceback into your question?

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed, Please find the traceback added. Note: I am not connecting to Salesforce DX org as we dont have DX setup. I am trying to connect to sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you've provided an incorrect Callback URL for your Connected App. The callback URL should generally be `http://localhost:8080/callback`.

This error arises because the callback URL you provided does not have a port number. However, it won't work at all because it appears you've provided an on-platform callback URL instead of a local URL, which CumulusCI uses to capture the refresh token.

To reiterate from my comment, unless you have a specific reason for creating your own Connected App, you do not need to do so. CumulusCI supplies its own out of the box. If you would like to use the built-in Connected App, remove the file `connected_app.service` from your local CumulusCI configuration directory.

Comment: Thanks so much @DavidReed, it worked. I just removed the file connected_app.service and its all sorted.